# couldnt load data for visual with filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

OLE DB or ODBC error: [Expression.Error] We couldn't fold the expression to the data source.

I am new in powerbi. I tried to visualize the table, and made measures on different manner (after google it), one of them:

```
Count1 =
CALCULATE(COUNTA('public history'\[old\]),
CONTAINSSTRING('public history'\[old\],"max_time"))
```

```
Count2 =
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('public history'),
FILTER('public history',CONTAINSSTRING('public history'\[old\],"max_time")))
```

'public history'[old] it just a STRING. But when I put them on page I got an error
Any suggestion?